# Not allowing users to resize a maximized form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a Windows Forms application in C# in which I have a form which must start in a maximized state and not allow users to restore or resize it. I have already configured the form to start in maximized mode, disable the restore and maximize button and locked the borders of the form but when the title bar is double clicked, the form restores to a smaller size which is unexpected. The following are the properties I set to achieve the required behaviour:

```
FormBorderStyle = FixedSingle
MaximizeBox = False
WindowState = Maximized
```

Can someone please help me solve this problem and explain me the solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just stick an onresize event handler on the form and put it back. One wonders why you are trying so hard to irritate your users though.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson So what you are trying to say is I set the "WindowState" to "Maximized" in the event handler code? 
Hey, hows that irritating someone?!!!!

Comment: @stuartd Did you mean to set the size of the maximized form to the "MinimumSize" property at runtime.

Comment: @hecate Added an answer, tested it and it doest resize when double clicking anymore

Comment: @Hecate it would irritate me, It's my windows installation, not yours. :)

Comment: This is useful when making application meant for terminal use such as a punch system

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to remember that your form starts with some default size values and double click is just toggling between 2 states.
Within your normal state the form will retrieve it's last ( in your case default ) size which you can override :

```
Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
```

Another thing is that your application has something called start position which ( from what I remember ) defaults to the center of the screen and you can change it using :

```
Form.StartPosition = new Point(0, 0); // top-left corner
```

Now all you have to do in your applicaiton is to check for the toggle between window states. Easiest way would be to use `WndProc` and wait for messages listed in [this msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646360(v=vs.85).aspx) :

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
    const int SC_MAXIMIZE   = 0xF030;
    const int SC_RESTORE    = 0xF120;

    if (m.Msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND)
    {
        switch((int)m.WParam)
        {
            case SC_RESTORE:
                // your window was restored ( double clicked on the command bar )
                // set it's window state back to maximize or do whatever
                break;

             case SC_MAXIMIZE:
                 // your window was maximized .. no actions needed, just for debugging purpose
                  break;
        }
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: This is a bit more elegant than my answer, learned some more! props to you

Comment: @m.rogalski Thanks for your help and effort :)

Answer (score 3):

This can be accomplished by catching the event and overriding it:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    this.MaximizeBox = false;
    this.MinimumSize = Screen.GetWorkingArea(this.Location).Size;
}

private const int WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x00A3; 
//double click on a title bar

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK)
    {
        m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
        return;
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort and help. Its not that your answer is incorrect or doesn't work as expected, but I'm going for the answer written by m.rogalski as its extremely well explained and detailed. 
SO must implement a system to accept 2 answers!!!! :)

Comment: @hecate I learned stuff from his answer, it should definitely be the accepted one! Thanks for the upvote :)